# layout-xxx/ causing TypeClass file collision: A resource exists with a different case: '....R$ID.class'

Tags: android, layout, screen-size

Everything is working fine with my Android project with the standard layout, however whenever I add a new layout-xxx subdirectory, say layout-large, and copy an XML file to it to be my baseline for the new size in question, from that point forward I get the error listed above and the project won't compile.

Location    TypeClass file collision: A resource exists with a different case: 'R$ID.class'

If I remove the xml file from the layout-xxx directory everything goes back to working fine.  I do have the support-screen tags in the manifest.

I can't possibly need to ID all my views and such inside my layout with seperate names for seperate layout files do I?  This would make coding so rediculously conditional that it would not be worth it.

What am I doing wrong? or missing?

Comment: You should definitely _not_ change layout ids; that would defeat the point of resource binding. Did you try cleaning your project after copying the file? Also, can you post an example of a layout that is giving problems?

Comment: Yes, I did run clean etc.. alas to no avail.  The layout is very simple  ScrollView with a RelativeLayout Inside.. and then various widgets.

Comment: @user756212: Is it something as simple as having a TextView (for example) in one layout file with an id of `textView1` and in another layout file called `textview1`? In other words, same name but differing only by upper/lower case characters.

Comment: No, its not a collision of different items having the same same id between view definitions.  I Seem to have resolved it by recopying the XML again.. but now am having problems with it not picking up the layout-large definitions.. is not WVGA854 not considered large under 2.2?

Comment: @user756212 - Not necessarily. Large refers to the screen dimensions, not the resolution. An ldpi, large screen can have fewer pixels across than an xhdpi normal screen. The emulator uses a mysterious formula (at least I haven't found any documentation for it) to combine the skin's pixel size and density with the display scaling to classify the emulated device.

Comment: Ted,
I did see that the default density for WVGA854 is indeed considered "NORMAL" so its not going to pick up the -large code unless I go and lower the DPI, for the emulator which I really don't want.  This is getting frustrating.  I developed the app using the HVGA mode 328*480 and it lays out lovely and works great, I put a droid size emulator on it and I wind up with a very large amount of the screen unused.. I was hoping to use layout-large to resolve this, but that's not going to work either... so how do I deal with this?  Both are considered "Normal" so how do I deal with the scaling ..

Comment: not really laying things out nice when moving to the longer screen.. if I much with the normal layout the HVGA users will have a screen too long.. if I leave it as is the DROID users will have a smaller screen that is available making useability a little more difficult...   Should I be investingating the "-long" aspect ratio for the WVGA850/54 users? is there such a thing as layout-long? Or is that just resources?

Comment: Layout-Long did the trick... thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today and it was because of my mistake.

I had my menu defined like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_share_action_provider_action_bar"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_bar_share_with">
        <menu >
            <item android:id="@+Id/someid"
                android:title="MyMenu"/>
        </menu>
        </item>
</menu>
```

Reason of error was ***Id*** with capitalized ***I*** which should be actually like ***id***

Hope this helps someone